# Change order of folders in the windows shell

Tags: windows-7, shell

In the shell of Windows 7, can I change the order of the folders displayed on some hierachy level? E.g., in Documents, I might have folders a, b, c, d, e and want to have the order a, c, e, b, d.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows files and folders are sorted by their attributes (name, date modified, type etc.). You cannot use a custom order.

Also, folders in trees are sorted alphabetically.

Comment: Well, it was worth trying